# UNION on 2 databases need UPDATE to work

Tags: mysql

I've created a UNION view that works well. But I need to UPDATE on this view and get an UPDATE error. How do I have to change this view syntax to be able to preform an UPDATE on these records?

This is my query;

```
SELECT 
    `DB1`.`wp_posts`.`ID` AS `ID`,
    `DB1`.`wp_posts`.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
    `DB1`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` AS `meta_key`,
    `DB1`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value`,
    `DB1`.`wp_postmeta`.`processed` AS `imported`,
    `DB1`.`wp_posts`.`processed` AS `postprocessed`
FROM (`DB1`.`wp_postmeta` JOIN `DB1`.`wp_posts` ON ((`DB1`.`wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `DB1`.`wp_posts`.`ID`))) 
WHERE ((`DB1`.`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound') AND (`DB1`.`wp_posts`.`processed` = 0)) 

UNION 

SELECT 
    `DB2`.`wp_posts`.`ID` AS `ID`,
    `DB2`.`wp_posts`.`post_date` AS `post_date`,
    `DB2`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` AS `meta_key`,
    `DB2`.`wp_postmeta`.`meta_value` AS `meta_value`,
    `DB2`.`wp_postmeta`.`processed` AS `imported`,
    `DB2`.`wp_posts`.`processed` AS `postprocessed` 
FROM (`DB2`.`wp_postmeta` join `DB2`.`wp_posts` ON ((`DB2`.`wp_postmeta`.`post_id` = `DB2`.`wp_posts`.`ID`))) 
WHERE ((`DB2`.`wp_posts`.`post_type` = 'flamingo_inbound') AND (`DB2`.`wp_posts`.`processed` = 0))
```

Comment: Post the update query you are using

Comment: I am updating these tables within Filemaker Pro, that shows my view. I am directly updating data in the table. Even if I use Navicat and I want to update for instance processed=1 I get this error.

Comment: The error I get when trying to update is: The target table KP_Support_Tickets_Combi of the UPDATE is not updatable